# Accessing Python module functions in a PyPI repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I've just uploaded my first Python module to PyPI and it seems to be working – but not quite as I had intended. The structure of my local directory for myProject is:

```
myProject/
    setup.py
    setup.cgf
    LICENSE.txt
    README.md
    myProject/
        __init__.py
        myFunctions.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty (although I've also tried it when it contains `__all__ = ['myFunctions']` but it makes little difference).
The `myFunctions.py` file defines several functions and helper functions, such as:

```
def myFunc1():
    print("Hello world!")

def myFunc2():
    print("It is an ex parrot.")
```

I've created a wheel, registered the project with PyPI and uploaded the project. So far, so good.

I had anticipated that I would be able to import the project into Python using `import myProject` and then access the individual functions, perhaps using `myProject.myFunctions.myFunc2()`. But, there seems to be no way to access the individual functions, I've tried all the variations I can think of.

However, I CAN assess the functions if I use:

```
from myProject import myFunctions
myFunctions.myFunc2()
```

So, at least I know that all the relevant code has been uploaded. Clearly I'm missing something critical but I haven't been able to find any reference to a solution in any of the tutorials I've read regarding how to upload to PyPI.

Does the `myFunctions.py` file need to have a special structure? Does the contents of `__init__.py` need to changed? Or do I need to change my setup.py file in some way? The contents of setup.py are given below:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
import pypandoc

# Haven't yet downloaded pandoc
try:
    long_description = pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')
except (IOError, ImportError):
    long_description = ''

setup(
    name = 'myProject',
    packages = find_packages(),
    version = '0.1.1',
    description = 'A library of Python code',
    long_description = long_description,
    author = 'A.N. Other',
    author_email = 'a.n.other@xyz.com',
    url = 'https://github.com/username/myProject', # use the URL to the github repo
    download_url = 'https://github.com/username/myProject/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz',
    license = 'MIT',
    keywords = ['keywords'],
    classifiers = [# How mature is this project? Common values are
                   #   3 - Alpha
                   #   4 - Beta
                   #   5 - Production/Stable
                   'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',

                   # Indicate who your project is intended for
                   'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
                   'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Medical Science Apps.',

                   # Pick your license as you wish (should match "license" above)
                   'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',

                   # Specify the Python versions you support here. In particular, ensure
                   # that you indicate whether you support Python 2, Python 3 or both.
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
                   ],
    install_requires=['pandas>=0.19.2'],
)
```

Any nudges in the right direction would be gratefully received.

Comment: `from .myFunctions import *` in `__init__.py` would do it. You can't define `__all__` with things that *aren't actually in the scope* and have them be magically located. Also note [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: If `__init__.py`'s only purpose is to provide the `myFunctions` functions, why not just use `myProject.py` as a file and skip creating a directory?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The suggestion to include `__all__` was taken from http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html but it didn't make a whole lot of difference. I'll try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: @zondo To be honest, I can't answer that. Pretty much all the snippets of code have been lifted from various tutorials on the subject and quite a few suggested this structure is the way it should be done (e.g. peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html and tom-christie.github.io/articles/pypi). However, I don't have enough experience to know whether that's correct or not.

Comment: @user1718097: Those also assume that you have multiple Python files. I don't know about any style guides in this area, but I'd probably just keep it to one file with no directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ... but on re-reading (and in light of your comments) I may have got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion - this worked a treat.